# Where are file operations handled in MVP?

Tags: c#, user-interface, file-io, mvp

This may be a silly question, but with my current searches I have found mostly information about the presentation of data and  the interplay between the Presenter and the View, but very little about the Model and the Presenter.

Basically, say I have a C# application, and it opens a CSV file that is a 5 by 5 array of numbers.  Now if I wanted to load that 5 by 5 CSV array into an array of ints, where is this handled in the grand scheme?

This is my current idea to follow MVP, but please correct me if I am wrong (or confirm that I'm right, if I manage to be).

1. The user clicks a button to load the file.
2. The View loads a showOpenDialog() for the user to select the file.
3. After user clicks okay in that dialog, the View, sends an event to the presenter containing that filename.
4. The presenter takes that filename, handles the file opening and parsing it into a 5 x 5 int array.
5. The presenter then provides that int array to the Model through an event.  The model then stores that array.
6. The model gives an event saying that it's data has changed.
7. The presenter listens and handles this event, putting that 5 x 5 int array into a DataTable.
8. The presenter raises an event saying that it has a new DataTableready.
9. The view listens and handles this event, and updates a dataGridView with the information provided by the DataTable.

My understanding of MVP gets murky at about step 5 there.  Is that how it should go, or did I misinterpret what each component does in MVP?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way of utilising events in MVP is interesting.. however I generally haven't come across it.

From my experience, this is the workflow:

1. Button clicked in view
2. View shows dialog
3. View stores filename in property
4. View calls Presenter method (e.g, loadFile)
5. Presenter uses View interface to retrieve file name from property
6. Presenter either a) uses a Service to perform loading or b) loads the file itself
7. Model is built either via the Service or Presenter
8. Model is passed back to view through the loadFile method

Comment: It wasn't as much "my way" as it was "my guess".  As a follow up question, when is it more appropriate to use a service to load files, than to have the presenter load them itself?

Comment: It depends. Generally when your business logic gets more complex. In my own applications I generally incorporate a Service layer either way.. but at work we always do, due to the level of logic.